# Retrieve SAML Data in iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios, saml, saml-2.0, wkwebview

I'm trying to access SAML Data that is appended to a POST request after a successful login however I can't find any information on how to do so.

I can retrive URL Request in the delegate method:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
```

However the navigationAction.request.HTTPBody parenter code hereameter is empty.

Thanks for any help or suggestions in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881800/in-ios-how-to-read-the-multi-part-form-data-in-the-nsurlrequest-originating-fro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In iOS, how to read the multi part form data in the NSURLRequest originating from a WKWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881800/in-ios-how-to-read-the-multi-part-form-data-in-the-nsurlrequest-originating-fro)